# ¿seria posible invocar una consola de admin de cmd, y ejecutar comandos en ella solo con el codigo html, o es necesario algo mas?

Tags: html, web, cmd

he estado mirando para cojer todos mis scripts en cmd y alguno en powershell para incrustar todo ese codigo en una pagina web, la idea es o poder ejecutarlo metiendolo directamente el codigo de la web, o alojarlo el github y ejecutar el codigo del archivo desde alli, el problema tanto para una o para otra es el poder invocar un cmd con permisos de admin en el propio ordenador, o usar una consola sin permisos y solicitar los permisos desde el codigo y cargar el codigo que tengo puesto en la web, pero no he visto ninguna solucion. el problema seria solo con el cmd puesto que el powershell lo puedo ejecutar desde cmd añadiendo un ps al principio. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Quieres incrustar scripts escritos para cmd y powershell en una página web para que un usuario desde un explorador web los ejecute? ¿No sería más fácil generar un archivo ```.bat``` con el script y que el usuario de la página web lo pueda descargar para correrlo en su computadora?

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer, pero supongamos que se pueda ejecutar el código de un script cmd en una web (cosa que no se puede), se estaría ejecutando en el servidor, no en tu computadora... o no se, no entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: a ver, la idea es que algunos scripts son bloqueados por el antivirus, ademas la idea es ponerlos en una web online, porque son casi 600 megas de archivos, y pues obviamente no te vas a descargar eso. o tu si lo harias?, y , la idea es que el codigo este incrustado en la web, y al hacer click en el script, invoque la consola y ejecute el codigo directamente en ella sin tener que descargar el codigo.

Comment: 600 megas en codigo? ejecutar un script en web supone un error de seguridad al servidor, a no ser que sea tuyo seguramente no te lo permitiran. cuando alguien te haga una pregunta no respondas de mala manera "a ver" y no sabes lo que obviamente alguien descargaria.

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta bien diseñada, ya que no se entiende que script ejecutar y porque ejecutarlos en servidor para descargar que?

Comment: vale, os lo explico mejor, la idea es alojarlos en un sitio como github, y que al cargar el codigo(cuando haces click en el nombre del script) y que la pagina solicite abrir una consola de cmd con permisos de administrador y cargar el codigo del script. la idea es que no tengan que descargar cada uno. A parte ya se que lo menciono en singular pero son exactamente 103 archivos. Dejando aparte el tiempo que consume, el problema es el ejecutarlos

Answer (score 0):

A nivel de cliente no se podría, se podría ejecutar en el servidor. Al ejecutarlo en el servidor se ejecutaría con el usuario que tenga el servidor, a menos que al ejecutar el script cambies el usuario por otro y lo ejecutes. Eso sí, a nivel de seguridad es una bomba.